# How to extract MDCT coefficients from audio files?

Tags: java, audio

I have an AAC file. I want to extract MDCT coefficients. Are there any libraries or tools in Java which can be used?

Comment: Do you need to extract them from the binary data or from the decoded wave?

Comment: I have a .acc audio file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this code](http://code.google.com/p/pjl/source/browse/trunk/DigitalAudioDemos/src/mediaframe/mpeg4/audio/AAC/MDCT.java?r=93) demonstrates the extraction of MDCT from AAC files.