# how to extract MDCT coefficients from wav files in matlab?

Tags: matlab, wav

i'm doing my final project right now, making a query by humming system in matlab using wav files input to search song in database. my method is using MDCT coeficients, i've searched everywhere but i just found the teory of mdct & polyphase filterbank.

because i'm really blank about matlab could you give me the code to extract mdct coeficient of wav files in matlab?

i found this [How to extract MDCT coefficients from audio files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229433/how-to-extract-mdct-coefficients-from-audio-files) but it's on java programming not in matlab.

waiting for your reply, i'm sory for my bad english..

Comment: WAV typically uses PCM as the audio encoding, so there are no MDCT coefficients.  You will need to be more specific about the encoding of your file.

Comment: actually, i want to extract mdct coeficients from mp3 files, i've already read mp3 files using mp3read with this : http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/mp3read.html

i want to compare mdct coeficient from mp3 files in my db, with humming from speech..